# SwiftUI Picker - # Stars based on ForEach iteration

Tags: swiftui, foreach, uiimage, picker

I'm trying to implement a picker which represents a star rating however I'm struggling to implement this in that each row id displaying only 1 star. Here's the code I have so far...

```
Picker("Rating", selection: $rating) {
            ForEach(1..<6, id: \.self) { rating in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(1..<rating, id: \.self) { star in
                        Image(systemName: "star")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a picker in which the first row will show 1 star, next row 2 stars, 3, 4 etc.
I'm convinced I'm butchering this code and there is most likely an easy solution but I have googled far and wide and yet I haven't stumbled across a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all things related to images but multiple images are not work in a single row so I have added `star emoji` as a string.

```
var body: some View {
        Picker("Rating", selection: $ratingg) {
            ForEach(1..<6, id: \.self) { rating in
                Text(String(repeating: "✩", count: rating))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @OxfordSi please check my answer and let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: Whilst this works, and I'm grateful for the response, I need to be able to use Image(systemName:) in order to apply colour.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Picker: View {

@Binding var selection: Int

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(1..<6, id: \.self) { rating in
            HStack {
                ForEach(1..<(rating + 1), id: \.self) { star in
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                        
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 4)
            .onTapGesture {
                selection = rating
                print("rating now is", selection)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in a picker - each row contains just 1 star. Thank you for taking the time to respond though.